# troubles installing lightfm python module,installed visual studio redistributable but still not working

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am facing troubles installing lightfm on my laptop.
When I try to install Lightfm,it gave me an error saying you need Microsoft visual c++.
I have installed microsoft visual c++ redistributable.
But still it is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install the [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux) it comes with tons of libraries.